# Storing names in array without path

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code that reads folder names given a path.

```
string[] dirNames =(Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\test\project\"));
foreach(string name in dirNames)
{
   Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Problem is that dirNames array is storing the directory name with path. While I just want to store the directory file name no path. I can remove it in the foreach loop but I want to store originally in the array with out path. Please let me know how to fix it. 
Thanks

Comment: You want it to show `projects` or `test/projects`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a new array (or list) in which the path is removed:

```
var dirNamesNew = dirNames.Select( x => x.Replace(path,"")).ToArray();
```

or in a single instruction:

```
string[] dirNames = (Directory.GetDirectories(path)).Select(x => x.Replace(path,"")).ToArray();
```

the Select will fetch the names, replace the path with no character, and then convert it back to an Array.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GetDirectoryName` from the `Path` class:

```
  foreach(string name in dirNames)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName( name ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
string[] dirNames = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\test\project\").Select(x => Path.GetDirectoryName(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `DirectoryInfo` and projecting the name for each directory:

```
var onlyDirectoryNames = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\test\project\").Select(x => new DirectoryInfo(x).Name)
```